# Functions defined as infinite products

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, tag-removed, special-functions, asymptotics

Are there standard references on infinite products of rational functions and their convergence properties? I'd appreciate information on finite products too!

The original motivation for this is the (finite) product $f(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-\frac{i}{i^2+n})$ that I had to bound some time ago. Applying some calculus (logarithm to convert into sum, relate to a series, bound with an integral) I could show that 
$f(n)>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac\pi{8n}$ if $n>9$ (and actually $f(n)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac\pi{8n}$ for big $n$) but I was left with the question whether there is a closed form for "my" finite product, or for the corresponding infinite product $\phi(n)=\prod_{i\ge 1}(1-\frac{i}{i^2+n})$(Any information on it would also make my day).

**EDIT May 17**: the infinite product $\phi(n)$ is zero (see Robert Israel's answer). Nevertheless, the square of $f(n)$ is $(1/n)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-(\frac{i}{i^2+n})^2)$, and it is still possible that the infinite product $\prod_{i\ge1}(1-(\frac{i}{i^2+n})^2)$ converges.

So, is there a place to look for techniques to deal with such products if the need arises?

Comment: "Infinite product" is a standard topic in complex analysis textbooks.
Closed form for your finite product seems unlikely.


Comment: @Gerald: Thanks! When I looked into this, I could not find anything useful, neither for the finite nor the infinite products -not in the textbooks I knew about. But I am no analyst, and I supposed there could be more specialized literature... Maybe it is too "old" a topic?

Comment: Since the terms in your product depend on $n$, the number of terms, what do you mean by the "corresponding infinite product"?

Comment: @Yemon: I edited the question to be concrete. If I recall correctly, the infinite version $\phi(n)$ is asymptotically close to $n^{-1/2}$ too.

Comment: @quim: the function $\phi(n)$ which you define can be handled using results from complex analysis that are often encountered when discussing infinite Blaschke products - I think there is something on this in Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis but I don't have my copy to hand. (Complex analysis is overkill, but because similar things arise when looking at Blaschke products, perhaps those books are more likely to mention the results you need.)

Comment: If memory serves correctly, a classic old book: Bromwich, *Infinite Series*, has a lot about products as well as sums [*but disclaimer: I haven't even looked at this book for at least 15 years!*] You might have some luck with various English mathematics books written before 1950, since this kind of thing was a lot more in fashion back then, at least in England  [*presumably due to G.H.Hardy's influence, although I am no historian*].

Comment: @Yemon, @Zen: Thanks a lot for the references! I do understand that complex analysis can be relevant. 

Comment: I don't think what you've written in your edit is correct. Also, perhaps a look in "Baby Rudin" (Principles of Mathematical Analysis) might show you the relevant convergence result. The basic idea is to take logarithms and be careful with your estimates.

Comment: What is written in the edit follows because f(n) equals 1/n times $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1+\frac{i}{i^2+n})$ (playing around with the fractions). 

Comment: So you let the n above the product sign go to infinity, but keep the n in the denominator fixed?


Comment: @Gerald Edgar: yes. My hope was that if the infinite product with $i\ge 1$ can be evaluated (as a function of n) then it might be that the infinite product with $i\ge n$ can be evaluated as well, and then it would be possible to deduce the value of the finite product.

Comment: Yes, $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - (i/(i^2+n))^2 ) $ converges (because $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (i/(i^2+n))^2$ converges), and Maple says it is ${\frac { \left( \sin \left( 1/2\,\pi \, \left( 1+\sqrt {1-4\,n}
 \right)  \right)  \right) ^{2}}{ \left( \sinh \left( \pi \,\sqrt {n}
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}$


Comment: @Robert Israel: Thanks again! And again, do you know where *this* closed form comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Maple, the finite product $f(n) = \frac{\Gamma(n - (1 + \sqrt{1-4n})/2) \Gamma(n-(1-\sqrt{1-4n})/2) \Gamma(1-\sqrt{-n}) \Gamma(1+\sqrt{-n})}
{\Gamma(n-\sqrt{-n}) \Gamma(n+\sqrt{-n}) \Gamma((1-\sqrt{1-4n})/2) \Gamma((1+\sqrt{1-4n})/2)}$.
The infinite product is 0, because $\sum_i i/(i^2+n)$ diverges.

Comment: I think I'll accept your answer, but do you have any idea where the Maple computation comes from? Is it related to the "Blaschke products" mentioned by Yemon Choi?

Comment: If n or 4n-1 are squares, then this does not work, right?

Comment: Well, as usual with such things, it may have indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$ at isolated values of $n$, but it extends to a continuous function of $n$.

Comment: Actually, the poles of $\Gamma$ being at _nonpositive_ integers, these problems won't arise for positive $n$.  For example, $f(n)$ has a singularity (a pole, I think) at $n=0$.  But of course that doesn't mean anything for the product. 

Comment: Yes, sorry, there are no problems (even indeterminations) for positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

For the Maple computation: write
$$
1 - \frac{i}{i^{2} + n} = \frac{(i - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{1 - 4 n}}{2}) (i - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{1 - 4 n}}{2})}{(i + \sqrt{-n}) (i - \sqrt{-n})}
$$
then write your product using four products of the form
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (i + a) = \frac{\Gamma (a+n)}{\Gamma (a+1)}
$$

Comment: Great! I got some valuable references to literature and even a closed form for that particular finite product. So thanks a lot. I wonder whether the relationship with $\sqrt{n}$ and $\pi$ is any easier using the Gammas... I'll have to work it out!